# GeoTools 10 - Convert Raster To Vector

Tags: geotools, raster-conversion

I am fairly green with GeoTools, and having a hard time converting a raster (GridCoverage2D) into a vector format.

In the hours I've spent searching this site and Google, there seems to be multiple ways this could be done: PolygonExtractionProcess, RasterToVectorFactory, RasterToVectorProcess to name a few.  However, regardless of what JAR's I reference in my project, I can't seem to find any of these classes.

So, I am hoping someone can tell me the easiest way to perform raster to vector with GeoTools 10.

Comment: did you have any luck with the raster to vector process. Currently, I am trying to do the same, and I run into problems with the class RasterToVectorProcess, which I can not find. perhaps my maven is pointing to the wrong place, but I don't know how to solve it. Any suggestions? <dependency> <groupId>org.geotools</groupId> <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId> <version>12-SNAPSHOT</version> </dependency>

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven, the classes and methods mentioned are within the wps package of geotools.

Its a good idea to clone the source from github.

It contains all additional plugins.